# Parse list of dynamic classes in gson android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I have a collection of classes, such as this:

```
    entityClasses = new HashMap<String, Class>();
    entityClasses.put("EntityType1", EntityType1.class);
    entityClasses.put("EntityType2", EntityType2.class);
```

I also have a JSON list of their instances as well:

```
String entityJSON = "[{"type":"EntityType1","name":"... attributes"},...]";
```

Where the *type* attribute will determine the class of the object that will be the target of JSON parsing. How can I parse these using gson?

I tried with the following:

```
String type = "EntityType1"; // I already can fetch this.
final Class entityClass = entityClasses.get(type);
new Gson().fromJson(entityJSON, new TypeToken<ArrayList<entityClass>>(){}.getType());
```

Which would work if *entityClass* was an actual class name, and not a variable that represents a class. In my case however, I get the following error:
**Unknown class: 'entityClass'**

So how is it possible to parse by a Class variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you get the type item of json manually and then pass the rest of json to Gson?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That's what i'm actually doing. The answer has been corrected.

Comment: This is not how type tokens are supposed to work. `TypeToken`s must declare its type parameters at the compile time, and you cannot substitute them at runtime. Simply create a mapping like `Map<Type, TypeToken<?>>` and describe every type token like new `new TypeToken<List<EntityType1>>(){}`.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without TypeToken? For a single entity I can do         EntityModel entity = gson.fromJson(singleEntityJSON, entityClass); Where EntityModel is the Base for all Entity classes

Comment: @user3156850 If you don't use type tokens, your `List`s will be just lists of `LinkedHashMap`s because Gson cannot obtain type information about the list elements -- Java does not retain type parameterization in objects themselves (unless you store it yourself), but only let's to keep it as field declarations, method declarations, or type declarations. `TypeToken`s use the latter, and this is where Gson can take the type info from. If you process a single entity, `Entity1.class` is fine, because it's exhaustive here, but without type tokens you can only do `List.class ` with `LinkedHashMap`s.

Comment: And yep, why your code cannot compile: in Java, generic types parameterization can only accept type names, not objects that represent classes (the type parameterization can only be resolved at compile-time), so that's why your compiler complains for unknown class `entityClass` (it just don't take your variable into account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can't do that since you should pass a class  as a generic type: not `List<String.class>`, but `List<String>`.

But you can use a workaround like this: store list `TypeToken`'s instead of list generic types:

```
entityClasses = new HashMap<String, TypeToken>();
entityClasses.put("EntityType1", new TypeToken<ArrayList<EntityType1>>(){});

...
String type = "EntityType1"; // I already can fetch this.
final TypeToken typeToken= entityClasses.get(type);
new Gson().fromJson(entityJSON, typeToken.getType());
```